# how to delete a in_shopping_cart with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

hello everyone i have a project where i have a shoppingcart,in_shopping_cart,product and all works fine, but i wanna delete the in_shopping_carts with ajax and not with html so i have this code:

### in_shopping_cart.rb

```
class InShoppingCart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :shopping_cart       
end
```

### shopping_cart.rb

```
class ShoppingCart < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products, through: :in_shopping_carts 
    has_many :in_shopping_carts
end
```

### product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :in_shopping_carts
  belongs_to :shopping_cart
end
```

### in_shopping_carts_controller.rb

```
def destroy
        @in_shopping_cart = InShoppingCart.find(params[:id])
        if @in_shopping_cart.destroy
            redirect_to carrito_path, notice: "El producto se elimino correctamente"
        else
            redirect_to carrito_path, alert: "Hubo un error, intenta de nuevo"
        end     
    end
```

### Application_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_shopping_cart

  private
   def set_shopping_cart    
    if cookies[:shopping_cart_id].blank?
        @shopping_cart = ShoppingCart.create!(ip: request.remote_ip)
        cookies[:shopping_cart_id] = @shopping_cart.id
    else
        @shopping_cart = ShoppingCart.find(cookies[:shopping_cart_id])
    end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
     @shopping_cart = ShoppingCart.create!(ip: request.remote_ip)
     cookies[:shopping_cart_id] = @shopping_cart.id             
   end
```

### show.haml

```
-@shopping_cart.in_shopping_carts.each do |i_sh|
   -product = i_sh.product       
   .col-lg-4
    .panel.panel-default
     .panel-title
      .pull-left
       %h1=product.name
       %span.label.label-success.no-padding.in-top
        ="#{product.stock} disponibles"  
      =render "delete_in_shopping_cart", product: product, i_sh: i_sh
```

### _delete_in_shopping_cart.haml

```
%button.red-text.button-active-pink.no-underline.pull-right.white.no-border{'data-toggle': "modal", 'data-target': "#"+"#{product.id}"}
 %i.fa.fa-window-close        
.modal.fade{id: "#{product.id}", tabindex:"-1", role:"dialog", 'aria-labelledby': "#{product.id}"}
 .modal-dialog{role: "document"}
  .modal-content
   .modal-header
    %button.close{type: "button", 'data-dismiss': "modal", 'aria-label': "Close"}
     %span{'aria-hidden': "true"}
      &times;
    %h4.modal-title.red-text{id: "#{product.id}"} Alerta              
   .modal-body
    %h4.text-center= "¿Estas seguro de eliminar #{product.name} del carrito?"           
   .modal-footer    
    = link_to "Aceptar",i_sh, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-success bold bottom-space"
```

the above code works absolutely fine! but i wanna destroy the in_shopping_cart with JS.

> i tried with this option

### _delete_in_shopping_cart.haml

```
= link_to "Aceptar",i_sh, method: :delete,remote: true, class: "btn btn-success bold bottom-space"
```

### in_shopping_carts_controller.rb

```
 def destroy
   @in_shopping_cart = InShoppingCart.find(params[:id])
   if @in_shopping_cart.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to carrito_path, notice: "El producto se elimino correctamente" }      
        format.js
      end

    else
        redirect_to carrito_path, alert: "Hubo un error, intenta de nuevo"
    end     
end
```

### destroy.js.erb

```
$("#in_shopping_cart_<%= @in_shopping_cart.id %>").fadeOut(500, function(){
    $(this).remove();   
});
```

### show.haml (added an ID in the column-lg-4)

```
-@shopping_cart.in_shopping_carts.each do |i_sh|
       -product = i_sh.product       
       .col-lg-4{id: "in_shopping_cart_#{i_sh.id}"}
        .panel.panel-default
         .panel-title
          .pull-left
           %h1=product.name
           %span.label.label-success.no-padding.in-top
            ="#{product.stock} disponibles"  
          =render "delete_in_shopping_cart", product: product, i_sh: i_sh
```

so far all works fine! but the view doesn't do anything. how can i refresh the Show.haml view?

```
  Started DELETE "/in_shopping_carts/108" for ::1 at 2017-04-27 20:30:04 -0500
Processing by InShoppingCartsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"108"}
  ShoppingCart Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "shopping_carts".* FROM "shopping_carts" WH
ERE "shopping_carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 112]]
  InShoppingCart Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "in_shopping_carts".* FROM "in_shopping_c
arts" WHERE "in_shopping_carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 108]]
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (4.0ms)  DELETE FROM "in_shopping_carts" WHERE "in_shopping_carts"."id" =
?  [["id", 108]]
   (213.2ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered in_shopping_carts/destroy.js.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "in_shopping_carts" ON "p
roducts"."id" = "in_shopping_carts"."product_id" WHERE "in_shopping_carts"."shop
ping_cart_id" = ?  [["shopping_cart_id", 112]]
  Rendered partials/_unlogged.haml (15.8ms)
  Rendered partials/_nav.haml (140.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1867ms (Views: 1609.7ms | ActiveRecord: 219.2ms)
```

im very noob with Rails&Ajax i can make a lot of things with HTML, but when i use ajax, there are momments where i cant finish something. some advice? thanks a lot my friends

Comment: Can you add the whole error you're getting with `Undefinided variable or method i_sh`?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma i already update the question my brother. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As in your destroy method your defining your `@in_shopping_cart` then your `destroy.js.erb` file will receive this one, you need to work with that object.

Asking to your last question, you need to bind the destroy action after the success to your destroy button which fired the event with the `ajax:success` callback, something like:

```
$('.btn.btn-success.bold.bottom-space').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
  $("#in_shopping_cart_<%= @in_shopping_cart.id %>").fadeOut(500, function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

This way you can handle it depending on the response you get maybe with `ajax:success`, `ajax:error` or `ajax:complete`.

Comment: palma your answer works to delete the in_shopping_cart but the view doesn't update :(

Comment: It's strange because you have two buttons to delete your record, one to fire the event and other to confirm, have you tried with both ways? did you do the repo?, did you see my repo with the example?